# Regular expression pattern matching for number,alphabetcic blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

Im having some strings like these

```
aa11b2s
abc1sff3
a1b1sdd2
```

etc....
i need to change these strings to these

```
aa 11 b 2 s
abc 1 sff 3
a 1 b 1 sdd 2
```

Simply saying..i need to add a space between each(number/alphabetic s) blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'aa11b2s';
console.log(str.replace(/([\d.]+)/g, ' $1 ').replace(/^ +| +$/g, ''));
```

Comment: If i use aa11b2.5s its getting aa 11 b 2 . 5 s  i dont want the space between the decimals..hw can i omit that

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = 'aa11b2s'.replace(/([a-z]+|\d+)(?!$)/gi, '$1 ');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = subject.replace(/[a-z](?=[0-9])|[0-9](?=[a-z])/ig, "$& ");
```

This matches a letter that's followed by a digit, or a digit that's followed by a letter, without *consuming* the second character.  Then it replaces the first character with the same character followed by a space.